# Can a Hankel matrix $H$ be efficiently decomposed into a linear combination of unitaries (LCU), so that $H=\sum_k a_k U_k$

Tags: quantum-algorithms, matrix-representation, classical-computing

Suppose I have a Hankel matrix of arbitrary size $N\times M=2^n\times 2^m$ for integers $n<m$ (the qubit numbers of two circuits I have at my possession), given by:

$H=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&\cdots & x_M\\x_2&x_3&\cdots& x_1\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\x_N&x_{N+1}&\cdots& x_{M+N-1}\\ \end{pmatrix}$,

with indices mod $N$. Does there exist an efficient method for decomposing this matrix into $H=\sum_{k=1}^T a_k U_k$ for certain unitaries $U_k$, such that $T\in\mathcal{O}(\text{poly}(m))$ at most? I know that you can take permutation matrices

$P_k=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \cdots 0 & 1\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & \cdots 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & \cdots 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$,

such that $H=\sum_{k=1}^{2^m} x_k P_k$, but then $T\in\mathcal{O}(\text{exp}(m))$, which is inefficient. Any ideas?

Comment: unitaries are square matrices. $H$ is not square, so cannot be written as a linear combination of square matrices.

Comment: For the square matrix, if you multiply by the exchange matrix $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|k\rangle\langle N-1-k|$, does that leave you with a circulant matrix? meaning you can diagonalise using a Fourier transform? So then you're just reduced to the problem of decomposing a diagonal matrix. Probably still exponential though!

Comment: @DaftWullie It is true that $U_k$ is not square, but I am using the definition of unitary here where the Hermitian conjugate of a matrix is equal to its pseudo-inverse. This idea was entertained at the end of https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-06-29-483/pdf/

Comment: If you're going to use a non-standard definition of "unitary", you need to spell that out super-explicitly in the question.

Comment: Efficient in what sense? How is $H$ given as input? It seems like the input size will be somewhere around $2^{n+m}$, so an algorithm polynomial in the input size could have runtime $O(\exp(n,m))$.